# Unity-Why is Z axis changing when I move an object on X axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in which I will be a cube. But when I move my cube on X axis the Z axis changes.
I've also blocked the X, Y, Z rotation.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CubeControl : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 input;

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
            input = new Vector3(25, 0, 0);
            rigidbody.AddForce(input);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
            input = new Vector3(-25, 0, 0);
            rigidbody.AddForce(input);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            input = new Vector3(0, 0, 25);
            rigidbody.AddForce(input);
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
            input = new Vector3(0, 0, -25);
            rigidbody.AddForce(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,share a snapshot of your inspector values of the the cube.
Also it would be better to use FixedUpdate instead of Update method since you are trying to apply a constant force.

Comment: @Billatron http://i.imgur.com/r7LFbi8.png

Comment: most likely its falling cause of gravity.

Comment: Sooo... What should I do?

Comment: try locking the position on Y axis on the rigidbody of the cube and see if that helps.

Comment: It is still not working :(

Comment: try explaining in a better way what you are trying to achieve by updating your question cause i can't see "what is not working".

Comment: Have you changed gravity direction? Usually it is affecting to -Y direction, not on Z axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're applying movement in world space.  You likely want to apply it in object space.  So you'll want to rotate the vector you generate by the objects transform.  Something like:

```
Vector3 input = new Vector3(25,0,0);
input = this.transform.rotation * input;
rigidbody.AddForce(input);
```

Also, a couple of things to make your life easier:

- Look into the [Input.GetAxis()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) stuff for doing input.  Can ease your life for setting things up/configuring later.
- I like using Vector3.up/Vector3.left/Vector3.forward etc. and multiplying by a scalar.  Makes things look more intuitive when wanting to multiply.